# Difference between /user and /root

Tags: kali-linux

hi can anyone help to to differentiate /usr and /root user. Does root user mean the person who build the kernel?.

Answer (score 5):

`/usr` is not a user, it's a directory for application data, `/root` is home directory for the `root` user, the system administrator account in Unix/Linux

These are very basic Unix/Linux concepts and I recommend not using Kali if you are struggling with these, you should pick a more user friendly and beginer oriented distribution like Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

Some more information about Linux filesystem hierarchy and concept of super user can be found here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser
- https://tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/root-account.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard
- https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/44425)